# How do I send mouse/keyboard input without triggering LLMHF_INJECTED flag?

Tags: windows, input, mouse

At the moment I use the [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) function but if you install a low level mouse hook the `LLMHF_INJECTED` is set indicating that the input was injected into the stream. Is there a way of sending mouse and keyboard input so that `LLMHF_INJECTED` is not set?

Answer (score 2):

Raymond Chen describes this kind of question as an Arms Race. Assume S is the technique to spoof such injections. Then one would see the question here, how do I detect if S was used to inject mouse/keyboard input? The point of this flag is that Microsoft decided that spoofing is possible but detectable.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is installing your own low level hook handler and clearing LLMHF_INJECTED inside it. This change seems to propagate to all other hooks down the chain.

Comment: *"down the chain"* - How do you now ensure, that your hook is always at the front of the hook chain, or at least in a relative position compared to the victim?